# Laravel: Many to Many insert

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am getting the error below when I try to insert data in my `skill_user` which has many to many relationship with users and skills table. User id no 14 exists in users table and skill id no 1 also exists in skills table.
The command that I execute is this `App\user::find(14)->skill()->save(1);`

> PHP error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Elo
>   quent\Model, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\tellworld-api\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ExecutionLoop\Loop.php(90) : eval()'d code on l
>   ine 1 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\tellworld-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany.php on
>   line 708

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a many-to-many relation in Laravel, you should use the [`attach()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) to link models.

So in this case, you can do the following:

```
App\user::find(14)->skill()->attach(1);
```

Comment: Where do you get null?

Comment: [This function does not return anything](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_attach), it just updates your relation in the database.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If this answer resolved your problem, please consider marking this as the solution so other users might find it.